# How to enable hibernate query timings for logging

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, logging, log4j

I am trying to add timing stats mechanism for hibernate queries. Our application.properties file already has entries like this :

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

So I tried to add : `logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG`. But this is not providing me with any timing info. Anyone know why?

edit :
I also added this to pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <hibernate.generate_statistics>true</hibernate.generate_statistics>
</properties>
```

still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set hibernate system property as well: **hibernate.generate_statistics=true**

One way you can set the System property is by using VM argument. In your case: **-Dhibernate.generate_statistics=true**

Comment: Please explain how you are running this application/code. Are you using Maven to run the code that uses Hibernate you are trying to debug or simply building the application artifact (war, jar) and then trying to debug it at runtime?

Comment: If you are not forking java process while doing it you can try passing as command line argument like this: **mvn -Dhibernate.generate_statistics=true** If this does not help share pom.xml fragment and mvn command you are using.

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks a lot for the help. there's very little help out there on enabling stats.